# Ubuntu: Cloned linux Ubuntu bootdrive slow to boot

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, usb-drive

I cloned my USB linux ubuntu bootdrive from sandisk ultra flair to kingston 3.0, the sandisk takes around 1min 30 sec to boot, but the kingston 3.0 takes 1 hour. I used the command:dd if=/dev/drive of=/dev/drive to clone the drive. I also tested the read speed with $sudo hdparm -tT /dev/drive and sandisk I got 50MB/S and kingston I got 100MB/S. Any reason why it's so slow to boot?

Comment: maybe it had to do an fsck because you copied a mounted filesystem?  is there anything on the screen when it is slowly booting?  any kernel messages?  maybe you plugged it into a usb2 (slow) port.

Comment: I have had many installs to USB3 drives most generic. Writing takes up to an hour, but reading is not that slow. Recently converted an old M.2 SSD to external drive and it is so much faster I may not use flash drives for installs, anymore. You do not have both drives plugged in when you reboot? You cannot have duplicate UUID/GUIDs.

Comment: Thanks oldred, I don't plug both drives in when I boot, just the one that's cloned, but it took 1 to boot compare to the original one just 3 minutes. Do you know any way to fix it?

Comment: hey toppk, I unmounted the drive going to clone before cloning it, when booting it's just normal, no error, just like the original drive, but it took me 1 hour to boot. Once booted, everything look the same, I can use it, apps are function, but It runs supper slow. I think it could be the drive I bought. Or software problems, not sure.